# Convert timestamp to DateTime with either php or MySql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I've been looking for more then 40 minutes now and I can't get it done.

I got this query:

```
$query = "SELECT id, title, timestamp FROM adafruit_articles ORDER BY timestamp ASC";
```

If I echo the timestamp in php then I get:

```
[timestamp] => 2012-04-30 19:14:59
```

I would like to get the month of it with a leading zero.
I can convert the timestamp to a integer but not to `DateTime`.

If I'm correct the last step would be:

```
date_format($date, "m")
```

but how can I get a `DateTime` of it?

In case MySQL is able to return only the month, I need also use the whole date somewhere so only returning the month from MySQL isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: `echo date('m', strtotime('2012-04-30 19:14:59'));`

Comment: date() function of php will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
$unix_timestamp = strtotime($row['timestamp']);
$date = date('m', $unix_timestamp);
```

---

> **m**: Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

You can get the date format you want from a MySQL query too:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(my_timestamp, '%d %M, %Y') AS my_timestamp FROM mytable WHERE... etc
```

Or you can do it in PHP like this:

```
$my_date = strftime('%d %M, %y', $row['my_timestamp']);
echo $my_date;
```